# Flattening an object model with Gorm?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

Is there a way I can easily flatten an object to one table in Gorm? I have several conceptual entities which *always* need to be joined to their parent class. That is, I have this:

```
class A{
   B other;
   String name;
   String value;
}

class B{
   String val1;
   String val2;
}
```

Is there a way to annotate this so that `val1` and `val2` appear exclusively in table A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `other` to the embedded list in class `A`:

```
class A{
   B other;
   String name;
   String value;

   static embedded = ['other']
}
```

See section 5.2.2, Composition in GORM: http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html

Answer (score 2):

Mark the field `other` embedded with a static property:

```
class A {
    B other
    String name
    String value
    static embedded = ['other']
}
```

The autogenerated schema will then contain two fields called `other_val1` and `other_val2` in the table for `A'.

If you want `B` objects to only be stored as part of an `A` object, move B.groovy from `grails-app/domain` to `src/groovy`